# Need to write to a string constant, how do I work around this?

Tags: c, pointers, cstring

I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    char *sPPhrase[51];

    /* Input */
    printf("Enter string (max. 50 chars):\n");
    fflush(stdout);                         /* Works around an annoying Eclipse bug that fails to display the output from the printf command */
    scanf("%s", *sPPhrase);   /* Won't work */

    /* More code goes here */
}
```

The `scanf()` command fails, I assume, because *sPPhrase is not writable as sPPhrase points to a string constant. The compiler doesn't have a clue of anything being wrong. A little later on, I need to pass this string to this function:

`char* reverse(char* sPPhrase[]);`

The string constant is not writable, but I need to pass this char* on to this function. How do I rewrite my code to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring an array of pointers, not a array of chars (commonly used as a string).

You need to declare like this:

```
char sPPhase[51];
```

Also, sscanf can get you in trouble: it's better to use fgets to read a string in a bounded buffer:

```
int main() {
    char sPPhrase[51];
    printf("Enter string (max. 50 chars):\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(sPPhrase, 50, stdin);  // leave one byte for '\0'

    // More code
}
```

I don't know what 'reverse' is doing, but you should probably define it as:

```
char* reverse(char* sPPhrase);
```

If it is doing the operation in place, you don't even need a return value.  If you do, don't forget to free it when you are done.

Comment: And change scanf to scanf("%s", sPPhrase);

Comment: Then how do I call the function? `char* sPReverse = reverse(sPPhrase);` generates this error:
"passing arg 1 of `reverse' from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: Like florin said above, it looks like your definition of `reverse` is flawed, in that it's expecting an array of pointers to char, as opposed to an array of char. Change the definition of reverse to `char *reverse(char *sPPhrase)`, so that the types match.

Answer (score 0):

Your decaration of sPPhase:

```
char *sPPhrase[51];
```

Is actually an array of 51 pointers.
What you actually want is just an array of characters:

```
char sPPhrase[51];
```

When you do that, you should change the scanf

```
scanf("%s",sPPhrase)
```

Also note that your scanf might read more than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you need to go back to how arrays are implemented in memory.  `char* sPPhrase[51];` is a declaration of a pointer to pointers, which you can think of as similar to a two-dimensional array.  If you declare this and call scanf to read into it, you set the value of an entire array equal to one character.  This is like saying:

```
char chars2D[50][50];
chars2D[0] = 'A';
```

What this is doing is setting an entire array equal to 'A', so that the memory address of the array is 'A'.  This is a garbage value in memory.  When you call `scanf("%s", *sPPhrase);` you are just multiplying the problem by attempting to set the top of each array equal to a letter.  So you get garbage.

[Here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread152048.html#) is a thread describing how to use scanf to read into an array of characters.